# How many ways Hibernate provide to access database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How many ways Hibernate provide to access database?

For example, I want to CRUD an object to database, I found out:

1. Using session from SessionFactory:
   session.save(object);
   ...
2. Using Hibernate Query Language.
3. Using Hibernate Criteria Queries.
4. Using Native SQL.

But I don't know what I should use. Please list your practice to access database in PRIORITY DECREASING ORDER and the reason why you do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Number 1) is directly required by 2) and 3). Number 4) defeats the object of Hibernate entirely. Between 2) and 3)? Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID and wants the associated entity, the use Session.get(). It's efficient, and makes use of the first-level cache to avoid reexecuting the query again and again.

If you need to get entities via other criteria (like all the users with a given first name, for example), then use JPQL queries. They are simple to write, very readable, and have less limitations than criteria queries.

If you need to take various optional criteria (like for a complex search form), the criteria API is the tool for the job. But it can't do everything a JPQL query does. There are other APIs available, and you can relatively easily write an API that generates dynamic JPQL queries if needed.

If you have a really complex query that can't be expressed using JPQL, then use SQL.

To write things to the database, queries should generally not be used, except in very specific circumstances where many entities must be modified the same way. Instead, get the entities to modify, and modify them. Hibernate will save their new state automatically.

Comment: I meant HQL. HQL is in fact a superset of JPQL, the Java Persistence Query Language. Hibernate is an implementation of the standard JPA (Java Persistence API)

Comment: thank you very much JB Nizet, you said that "The HQL (JPQL) have less limitations than criteria queries". What are the Criteria limitations?

Comment: It can only select from one root entity, for example. IIRC, it doesn't allow multiple joins on the same association either.